# AttributError: 'module' object has no attribute 'application'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, communication, web.py, raspbian

I followed this exercise http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial to see how it works but an error occurred and I can't solved it.

I did this on my raspberry to send data/lines like hello world to the pc

sudo apt-get install python-webpy

```
mkdir webpy
cd webpy
nano server.py
```

Thn i typed in the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()`enter code here`
Then I control+x to save under the name server.py
```

I first tried `python server.py`

Then `chmod +x server.py thn ./server.py`

But both resulted

```
traceback (most recent call last):
 File server.py, line 11 ,in <module>
app - web.application(urls, globals())
AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'application'.
```

I don't know whether maybe my web.py is not downloading the latest one to be using the following commands since mine is using raspbian.

Comment: Do you have a `web.py` file in the same folder as your `server.py`? That can cause this problem...

Comment: inside /home/pi/webpy  is (web.py,webpy folder) & server.py interms of code(picture of a gear on the paper)

Comment: inside web.py is empty

Comment: If you first started by calling your file `web.py`, rather than `code.py` as in the Python tutorial, you might also have a `web.pyc` "byte code" file created in the folder where you are coding. After discovering the name collision, make sure you also delete the `web.pyc` file.